# Limit of sequence involving definite integrals in limits of other definite integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the first few terms of a sequence $u_n$:

$$u_0=\int_0^1x\mathrm{d}x$$
$$u_1=\int_{\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}x\mathrm{d}x}^{\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{2}{2}}x\mathrm{d}x}x\mathrm{d}x$$
$$u_2=\int_{\int_{\int_{\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}x\mathrm{d}x
}^{\frac{1}{4}}x\mathrm{d}x
}^{\frac{2}{4}}x\mathrm{d}x}^{\int_{\frac{2}{4}}^{\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{\int_{\frac{3}{4}}^{\frac{4}{4}}x\mathrm{d}x
}x\mathrm{d}x
}x\mathrm{d}x}x\mathrm{d}x$$

I have tried to evaluate $\log_2|\frac{1}{4u_n}|$ numerically for $n$ upto 30. The following table shows results I got.

```
   n    log2(abs(1/(4*u_n))
   0    -1.0000000000000000
   1    2.0000000000000000
   2    6.1455489157258656
   3    7.2412392591821595
   4    8.2903714596194842
   5    9.3022187426994964
   6    10.3051852537278439
   7    11.3059271976126663
   8    12.3061127036613751
   9    13.3061590814330852
  10    14.3061706759550180
  11    15.3061735745906695
  12    16.3061742992498218
  13    17.3061744804163098
  14    18.3061745257037281
  15    19.3061745370240523
  16    20.3061745398518347
  17    21.3061745405281400
  18    22.3061745407401126
  19    23.3061745408176186
  20    24.3061745410085699
  21    25.3061745406151104
  22    26.3061745413991375
  23    27.3061745382616650
  24    28.3061745398303408
  25    29.3061745304181436
  26    30.3061745492425274
  27    31.3061745617921154
  28    32.3061744362962457
  29    33.3061745366929429
  30    34.3061746370896401
```

Based on above result I am guessing that limit of the sequence $\log_2|\frac{1}{4u_n}|-n \in (4,4.5)$.

Is there a way to prove this analytically?

Comment: Just out of curiosity : which tool did you use for the computation ? Interesting problem and $\to +1$

Comment: @claude I wrote some code to calculate that myself https://gist.github.com/vyuh/8e2c74f49a97a9ade738d58c5151a1c0

Comment: applaud, applaud

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My interpretation of your question is as follows: Define

$$I(a, b) = \int_{a}^{b} x \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$$

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer, and let $(a_{n,k})$ and $(b_{n,k})$ be defined by the following recursive formula:

\begin{align*}
a_{n,0} &= 0, & a_{n,k+1} &= I\left(I\left(a_{n,k}, \tfrac{k}{2^n}\right), \tfrac{k+1}{2^n}\right), \\
b_{n,1} &= I\left(\tfrac{2^n-1}{2^n}, 1 \right), & b_{n,k+1} &= I\left(\tfrac{2^n-k-1}{2^n}, I\left(\tfrac{2^n-k}{2^n}, b_{n,k}\right)\right).
\end{align*}

Then $ u_n = I(a_{n,2^{n-1}}, b_{n,2^{n-1}}) $.

---

Here is a heuristic argument for the asymptotic behavior of $u_n$.

To analyze $(a_{n,k})$, we make an ansatz that $(a_{n,k})$ has an asymptotic expansion of the form

$$ a_{n,k} = f_0 \bigl(\tfrac{k}{2^n}\bigr) + f_1 \bigl(\tfrac{k}{2^n}\bigr) \Delta x + o(\Delta x) \tag{1} $$

for $\Delta x = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and for some nice functions $f_0, f_1$. Under this assumption, we will identify the functions $f_0$ and $f_1$. Write $x = \frac{k}{2^n}$ for simplicity. Then by comparing the constant-order terms of both sides of the recurrence relation

$$ a_{n,k+1} = I\left(I\left(a_{n,k}, x \right), x + \Delta x \right), $$

it follows that that $f_0(x)$ solves

$$ f_0(x) = \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^2 f_0(x)^2}{4} - \frac{x^4}{8} - \frac{f_0(x)^4}{8}. $$

The only solution of this equation that makes sense is

$$ f_0(x) = \sqrt{1+x^2} - 1 . $$

Plugging this back to the recurrence relation and then comparing the terms of order $\Delta x$, we obtain

$$ f_1(x) = \frac{x^3}{(1+x^2)(1+\sqrt{1+x^2})(2-\sqrt{1+x^2})}. $$

Numerical simulations provides strong evidence that $\text{(1)}$ is indeed the case:

[image: simulation of f_0]

[image: simulation of f_1]

Likewise, if we assume that

$$ b_{n,k} = g_0 \bigl(\tfrac{k}{2^n}\bigr) + g_1 \bigl(\tfrac{k}{2^n}\bigr) \Delta x + o(\Delta x), \tag{2} $$

then we can check that $ g_0(x) = -f_0(1-x)$ and $g_1(x) = f_1(1-x) $. So, assuming $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$,

\begin{align*}
u_n
&= I\left(f_0\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr) + f_1\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr)\Delta x + o(\Delta x), -f_0\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr) + f_1\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr)\Delta x + o(\Delta x)\right) \\
&= -2 f_0\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr) f_1\bigl(\tfrac{1}{2}\bigr) \Delta x + o(\Delta x).
\end{align*}

Plugging the formulas for $f_0$ and $f_1$, this simplifies as

$$ u_n = - \left( \frac{32 - 14 \sqrt{5}}{55} + o(1) \right) \frac{1}{2^n}. $$

Therefore,

$$ \log_2\left|\frac{1}{4u_n}\right|
= n + C + o(1), $$

where $C$ is the constant given by

$$ C = - 2 - \log_2\left(\frac{32 - 14 \sqrt{5}}{55}\right) \approx 4.306174540802602. $$

This correctly predicts the outcomes of the simulation:

[image: simulation]

Comment: This is pure beauty ! When I see this kind of answer, I feel more than miserable. Cheers :-)

Comment: @Sangchul I was finally able to obtain the equation from recurrence relation, now I'm stuck at solving the quartic equation for $f_0(x)$. I guess this is a hard problem and this answer might be as accessible as possible. It'll be helpful if you can link me to some example of solving similar equation.